# Would Hu's algorithm work for general unit-length edge DAG's?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, scheduler

According to http://www-labs.iro.umontreal.ca/~dift6221/demicheli4/sch2.4.ps.pdf, Hu's algorithm is optimal when the graph is a tree. Would it fail for general unit length edge DAG's? What's the reason why it's not optimal in such cases? Any examples of such failures?

Comment: I was able to come up with a border line counter example. Say you can do at most 10 tasks in parallel. There are 30 tasks. 1~10 must be done before 11. 12 must be done before 13~30. If you go with Hu's and get unlucky, you may do 1~10 first, then you do 11 and 12, then 2 more rounds to finish. That's 4 rounds. The best way is to do 12 to unblock 13~30 first, so first round you do 12, 1~9, second round 10, 13~21, then 3rd round 11, 22~30. That's 3 rounds and no waste. I want to see better examples though.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while but I was able to come up with a couple of counter examples. The key is to have a shallow task block a large number of tasks, which is not allowed in an in-tree.

Say at most you can execute k=10 tasks in parallel. You have 40 tasks, labelled 1 through 40.

Tasks 1~10 block task 11 which blocks task 12. (This is an in-tree. So far so good.)
Now task 13 blocks tasks 14~40. (13 has multiple parents, a violation)

With the greedy algorithm, tasks 1~10 have be be done in the first step, leaving 13 still blocking 14~40. Step 2 can only process 11 and 13. Now the algorithm can't finish in 4 steps, which is the best you can do.

The optimal schedule is to do 13 and say 1~9, unblocking 14~40, and finish in 4 steps without any worker idling.